# When to use '<event>'(event, instance) and when to use '<event>':function (event)?

Tags: meteor

I'm new to meteor, and I've followed different tutorials that explain and use things differently.

There seems to be two ways of processing an event. For example, if I want to manage a click on a

tag, both of the following methods work :

This one is present on the hello world meteor app

```
'click p'(event, instance) {
 }
```

This one is the one used in the tutorial.

```
'click p': function(event){
 }
```

Both work perfectly and if I use both the last one will be effective. The weird thing is the color is not the same (on sublime text), the second has usual js colors but the first one is only green, orange, and everything else is white (on monokai).

I'm tempted to use the second one for better visibility, but I know I should not make that choice base on that. Which one is correct, and when ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bottom line**: it doesn't really matter if you only need the `event`.

---

There are 2 syntactic differences between the functions, but there is no substantial difference:

1. The notation that you are using:

   ```
   funcName(arg1, arg2)
   ```

   vs

   ```
   funcName: function(arg1, arg2)
   ```

   The **highlighting coloration difference** you see in your editor is probably related to the **shorthand notation**. This [shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) is a feature of **ES2015**, the relatively new version of JS, and both are functionally identical. It is just **syntactic sugar**.
2. The **arity** (number of arguments).
   The function is used as an event handler as a callback. Due to the dynamic nature of JavaScript, any function can be **called with any number of parameters**. The parameters are being **assigned to arguments** based on the function's definition, and are also dynamically available to the called function via the [**`arguments` pseudo-array**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

The callback will always be called with 2 parameters. In the version with 1 argument, the second parameter will not be bound to any identifier within the function. You can omit the second argument if you don't need the template instance.